# Cplex.IntParam.WorkDir property has incorrect value when calling Cplex from C# in Visual Studio 2015 and not creating Node Files

Tags: .net, cplex, ilog, integer-programming

I'm calling cplex from C# in Visual Studio 2015.

```
Cplex cplex = new Cplex();
```

I check the value of Cplex.IntParam.WorkDir (using cplex.GetParam(Cplex.IntParam.WorkDir)), and it gives me the following value
".\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

Then I execute the following line of code,

```
cplex.SetParam(Cplex.IntParam.WorkDir, "D:\\Temp\\cplex");
```

And now, the value of Cplex.IntParam.WorkDir is 
"C:\TEMP\cplex\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

When I call cplex.Solve(), after building the model, at no point in time, are node files actually created in the directory "D:\TEMP\cplex", even when I put the value of WorkMem to something extremely low as 128 MB. Memory consumption extends to my RAM capacity and then errors out despite the value of 
    Cplex.IntParam.NodeFileInd being set to 3.

I tried writing out the model file, to see where it would write it, and it was in the default directory of the project.

Does anyone know why no node files are created? And why IntParam.WorkDir gives this value and how to actually force cplex to create node files when it runs out of memory?

Comment: What version of CPLEX are you using? VS 2015 is not supported (see the [system requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100)), but you can create projects within VS 2015 that use VS 2013 libraries, etc.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: I can confirm that you get that ugly output when printing the WorkDir parameter.  You can do something like the following to clean it up: `cplex.GetParam(Cplex.Param.WorkDir).Trim('\0')`.  The ugly output is due to the fact that the string is stored internally as a null-terminated string in the C Callable Library.  I don't think it should affect the behavior, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can force node files to be created with code like the following:

```
cplex.SetParam(Cplex.Param.MIP.Limits.TreeMemory, 1);
cplex.SetParam(Cplex.Param.WorkMem, 1);
cplex.SetParam(Cplex.Param.WorkDir, ".");
cplex.SetParam(Cplex.Param.MIP.Strategy.File, 2);
cplex.WriteParam("param.prm");
```

With that you should see file names like "cpxdczQeT".  Note how I write out the parameter file on the last line above.  This is a good way to make sure that the parameters are set correctly.

Lastly, could it be that your problem is solved to optimality at the root node?  In that case, CPLEX does not even need to start branch and bound, and no node files are created.